# Shortcut for adding quotes causes program to quit

Tags: bug, editing

While editing a long answer with a large block of text to quote, I held my mouse over the button for quoting, and noted that the shortcut to add quotes is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

The use of 'Q' makes sense, but it is also used to quit at least FireFox and Vivaldi!

Can this be changed in the website?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Uh oh, just tested it and Vivaldi behaves differently depending on whether the text field is focused: If it is, Ctrl+Q actually puts highlighted text in a blockquote, only if it isn’t Vivaldi closes. This is not as bad as I thought it would be, not at all. One could still argue it’s a poor shortcut decision as Ctrl+Q is used for “quit program” in *many* applications, but at least it’s not interfering – unless of course you wanted to close your browser in the middle of writing a question. [Every change breaks someone’s workflow.](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: @dessert For me on Firefox, even with the text field focused (and highlighted) ctrl+q, causes Firefox to try to quit.  Not the end of the world, but an annoying thingy.  Not really a bug, just thingy.  You can always just click the icon...

Comment: Unless you have no pointing device. :)

Comment: @dessert Then I would have difficulty moving about the page, and worring about how to get a pointing device!

Comment: There are very good solutions to this, I use https://vimium.github.io and rarely touch the mouse. Of course that’s a matter of taste.

Comment: @dessert Me :== Lazy

Comment: I went and posted this over at https://meta.stackexchange.com also

Comment: Also here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323147/ctrlq-shortcut-for-adding-quotes-causes-firefox-to-quit

Comment: @DKBose Ayuh - that's my post!

Comment: I do not want to close Firefox while writing answer with quote. Please fix this bug.